# PHP mail function not working when sender email is Yahoo id?

Tags: php, wordpress

PHP `mail()` function is not sending email when sender email id is Yahoo id. It is working fine for other accounts like Gmail. what are the possible reasons behind that?

I am using following code

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@gmail.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: username@yahoo.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

I also tried `wp_mail` for WordPress but the results are same.

Comment: This is likely to be due to the message going into spam/junk.  Email is a difficult beast to tame to get predictable results in my experience.

Comment: yahoo blocking your email as spam and automatically dumping as your not sending via a proper mail server with valid SPF records etc.

Comment: @Dave what will be the solution for this ?

Comment: use smtp authorization for example use [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or any other lib that allows to smtp auth

Comment: As well as the above library, consider SwiftMailer too.

Comment: swiftmailer + a proper mail server to send through with a valid return path account rather than sending via the webserver will get past it.  Ensure the mailserver is correctly configured with spf/txt entries and ideally DNSEC setup etc too. Sending via an smtpd on the localhost of a webserver is 99% of the time bad / highly likely to get canned as spam